# Write a program that prints the multiplication of two selected numbers from a line

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

The first line of input tells how many lines there will be. The first number of each line, n>=4 and n<=1000, contains the number of integers that follow in the line. Those n integers (each integer >=0; <=1000) follow until the end of the
line, and should be stored (except the last two) in an array using index
numbers 1…n-2. The last two integers x, y (x,y>=1 & x,y<=n-2) in the line is the index (starting from 1) of the integers from the line to multiply and print

```
Input:
3 //
5 13 2 5 1 3 //
6 5 3 6 7 4 2 //
9 7 12 2 14 5 7 9 6 3 

Output:
65 //
21 //
14
```

I understand how this code is supposed to work, but I am very confused on how to use scanner to separate the information that will be given by the user. How do I specify that the first number inputted will be number of lines? How do i specify that the next number will list how many numbers are in each line? - This is in java by the way

Comment: probably jquery

Comment: Why is there a javascript tag?

Comment: Hello Kori and welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't the place to get someone to do your homework for you rather a place to ask for help when you are stuck with a specific issue. I don't think you will find many people willing to do your homework for you here.

Comment: I'm not trying to get anyone to do my homework, I simply listed the full problem to try and avoid questions about it later. All I am really asking for is some help with scanner as I haven't used it much before and I don't understand how I am able to separate input given by scanner for different purposes.

Comment: Then you need to ask that question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did ask that at the end of the original question already. I don't know the best way to explain my question without listing the full scope of it, which means putting in what I need scanner to do, which is what I did

Comment: You haven't put up any code to show us what you've tried

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int number = in.nextInt();
 for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) { 
  int intNumber = in.nextInt();
  for (int a = 0; a < intNumber; a++) { 
   int array[] = new int[intNumber-2];
   **stuff I need help with here**
   int mult1 = intNumber-1.getValue();
   int mult2 = intNumber-2.getValue();
   System.out.println(mult1*mult2); 
}}
in.close();
}}
So what I don't get I guess is if this would actually do what it should and how to add the scanner input to an array so i can get the values at needed indexes

Comment: Sorry it looks rough i'm not sure how to format it correctly on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run something like this:

```
int numOfLines; //stores num of lines that will be inputted
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  //assuming you already imported before this

numOfLines = reader.nextInt(); //captures 1st user inputted value

int[] nums = new int[numOfLines];  //creates array object to captures all further values

for (int i = 0;i<numOfLines-1;i++){
nums[i] = reader.nextInt();  //captures values and stores in Array nums
}
```

Hope this can give you at least an idea of what to do. This will allow you to then afterwards calculate the multiplied values.

Comment: So you're essentially making an array of all values inputted after you have the amount of lines it will have. My question for you is how would you determine the specific lines in your array? like you create the array to have 3 lines, but how does this go about breaking the lines where they end?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "breaking the lines", but code will create an array just large enough to store the number of values you indicated in the very first input.

Comment: So what I mean is that the first input for this is supposed to be the number of lines there will be. In my example it was 3. Then, the second indicates how many integers will be part of the first line. In my example, that's 5. So if this holds only 3 values because that's what the first number was, how can it be adjusted so that it holds 3 lines but also has 5 integers after 5? Would this need to be a 2D array?

Comment: Oh...I believe I misunderstood your original meaning. You would have to create a new array for each new "line" of data. Plus using the Scanner object, you would have to hit "enter" each time to input the value

Comment: Ok so if I put it inside a for loop would that work? I am used to having test cases from my other professor so it's hard for me to test my own code at this stage please forgive all the questions.

Comment: You would need to create multiple nested for loops. One for creating a new "Line" of data while then you would have to include a loop for creating a number of arrays according to initial input, THEN have a nested for loop INSIDE that created array asking for the amount of numbers that will be inputted. btw if you could accept my answer with the green checkmark, that'd be great :D.  When do you need this project finished by? I can help you some more tmrw as I am very busy tonight.

Comment: meaning a for loop that iterates until that initial number is met and then a nested for loop that iterates until the next integer that is read is complete and puts it all into an array then outside that for loop is when it looks at the specific integers and goes from there? Does that make any sense haha it's hard to explain without showing the code but i'm not sure how to put it in here without making it too messy

Comment: don't post your entire code on here, it will be too much and cluttery. At most, if you really want to share it (I would highly NOT recommend posting all your hard work on a site) you could use a pastebin link.

Comment: understood. it's due tomorrow but I've been working on it all day and would like to have it done before I go to bed. Anyway, I believe I have one final question - in terms of putting the line that will determine my output, that's best to have inside the nested for loop where i fill my array right? that way when the outer for loop iterates again it won't delete it before I am able to find the answer?

Comment: You will have to make new arrays for every new "Line" of data, they will not disappear, the hard part will be to write the "equation" to multiply all of the data together and then store it as ANOTHER array and finally output the final array using one last for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole line instead and separate it using the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) function of the String class. Split returns an array with all the numbers in it then parse each token with [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) to convert it from String to Integer.

n will be in the first position in the array (array[0]) x will be in array[array.length - 1] and y will be in array[array.length - 2] the rest of the elements (from 1 to array.length - 2) are the numbers you want.

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying but I'm confused on how I can make the first number inputted directly related to the number of lines I have. I think what you're saying would best fit inside my inner for loop and then add a print line to get the multiplication of the values i need, but i guess the initial part of it which determines how many lines is what's tripping me up now. Thank you so much for the help